# Reference tags in rich text fields parse and converted on save

Tags: reference-tags

In my rich text field, I have a reference tag: `{globalset:34:address}`.

When I save and open the entry back up, the content is no longer a reference, but the parsed content, which sort of eliminates its usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct... they currently only work on plain text fields, not rich text fields.

I just updating the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags) so it's a more clear.

Comment: +1 for this feature request too. :-) is there a place we can officially register a vote on this?

Comment: @TerryUpton http://feedback.craftcms.com