# Globals (template tags) in entries?

Tags: templating, entries, tags, globals

Is it possible to use template tags within an entry? Specifically, I'd like to use Globals I've set up within an entry, so I can manage a brand name globally.

Comment: Found an answer you guys!

http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/is-it-possible-to-use-twig-in-a-rich-text-field

Answer (score 3):

You can, using [reference tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags), but unfortunately they only work in plain text fields:

[Reference tags in rich text fields parse and converted on save](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/reference-tags-in-rich-text-fields-parse-and-converted-on-save)

Comment: Couldn't tell from the question where dgrebb wanted to display the info, so posted another option. I always forget about ref tags. Thanks Tim!

Comment: Check it out! 

http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/is-it-possible-to-use-twig-in-a-rich-text-field

Comment: @dgrebb That's pretty cool. Good find. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from your question where you are trying to display the information.

- If displaying in a template then you can access the [global](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/globals#templating) directly `{{ globalSetHandle.fieldHandle }}`.
- If displaying within another textfield then, as Tim suggested, using [reference tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/reference-tags) is great idea (I would have never thought of that, Tim!)